# SQLite: Numeric values in CSV treated as text?

Tags: sqlite

I just imported a huge text file into a table, using the .import command. Everything is OK, except for the fact that it seems to treat clearly numeric values as text. For instance, conditions such as `WHERE field > 4` are always met. I did not specify datatypes when I created the table, but this doesn't seem to matter when small tables are created.

Any advice would be welcome. Thanks!

Edit/conclusion: It turns out some of the values in my CSV file were blanks. I ended up solving this by being a bit less lazy and declaring the datatypes explicitly.

Comment: are you sure theres nothing wrong with your query? can you provide an example?

Comment: @hexa, the query isn't necessarily wrong. This sort of results make sense if the CSV importer implicitly creates columns of affinity `TEXT` in SQLite.

Comment: @Bruno also all the fields might really have a numeric value higher than 4, who knows. it's hard when we don't have anything to look at.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. The values I'm working with are both > 4 and < 4, for sure. Also, all the values in the column are clearly numeric, which is what puzzles me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way SQLite handles types is described on this page: http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

In particular:

> Under circumstances described below,
>   the database engine may convert values
>   between numeric storage classes
>   (INTEGER and REAL) and TEXT during
>   query execution.

Section 3.4 (Comparison Example) should give you concrete examples, which are likely to explain the problem you have. This is probably this example:

> ```
> -- Because column "a" has text affinity, numeric values on the
> -- right-hand side of the comparisons are converted to text before
> -- the comparison occurs.
> SELECT a < 40,   a < 60,   a < 600 FROM t1;
> 0|1|1
> ```

To avoid the affinity to be guessed, you can use `CAST` explicitly (see section 3.2 too):

> SQLite may attempt to convert values
>   between the storage classes INTEGER,
>   REAL, and/or TEXT before performing a
>   comparison. Whether or not any
>   conversions are attempted before the
>   comparison takes place depends on the
>   affinity of the operands. Operand
>   affinity is determined by the
>   following rules:
>
> - An expression that is a simple reference to a column value has the
>     same affinity as the column. Note that
>     if X and Y.Z are column names, then +X
>     and +Y.Z are considered expressions
>     for the purpose of determining
>     affinity.
> - An expression of the form "CAST(expr AS type)" has an affinity
>     that is the same as a column with a
>     declared type of "type".
> - Otherwise, an expression has NONE affinity.

Here is another example:

```
CREATE TABLE test (value TEXT);
INSERT INTO test VALUES(2);
INSERT INTO test VALUES(123);
INSERT INTO test VALUES(500);

SELECT value, value < 4 FROM test;
2|1
123|1
500|0
```

It's likely that the CSV import create columns of affinity `TEXT`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is a work project, and I will next try to just declare the datatypes explicitly. But I was hoping that a column full of '0's, '2.3', '8.3', etc. would not lead SQLite to apply text affinity. I will update this post with more results.